# Laravel migrate rollback cancel

Tags: laravel, migration

I tried to rollback a specific migration, I ran `php artisan migrate:rollback`, but I forgot to include `--step=1`, now all the migration files `Ran?` status is **No**, How do I cancel the rollback? Or is it possible at all to cancel the rollback? I do not want to re-migrate all of the migration files.

Comment: for rollback you can check in database `migrations` table which ran and customize that for usecase

Answer (score 0):

migrate:rollback will rollback the last batch of migrations, maybe it only rolled back a few depending on your database.

My suggestion is to backup your database, then run artisan:migrate to see how many migrations get generated.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#rolling-back-migrations

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess there's really nothing you can do about rollbacked migrations.
The best option I got not to lose existing records was to dump the database, run migration, then import the dump file.